# How can i make ubuntu 32 bit desktop to come back to non gui mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I installed ubunut 15.10 desktop on  VM and assign 1core and 1 GB RAM.

It looks very slow.

Is there any way that when i start it go back to terminal mode only without all GUI stuff so that speed is fast

Comment: You can do it in more than one way. See [Runlevel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel). By default level 5 is the graphical run level, and level 3 (or 2 in Debian's case) are text mode. I  will post an answer later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A VM is just another pc with a given OS, so you can do it whichever way you prefer (there are many) just like you would in a real pc. In particular, my favorite is

```
sudo systemctl disable lightdm
```

(if you are using lightdm as a display manager, otherwise change it accordingly). At the next reboot you will find yourself in a text-only mode. You can then start the graphical mode by means of

```
startx
```

if you use Gnome/Unity, or

```
startkde
```

if you use KDE. Since you are already logged in, you will **not** be prompted for credentials again (in other words, you bypass lightdm to go to the window manager directly).